# SQS SendMessage abnormal/one-off delay

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an event for my s3 bucket that triggers my lambda function to write messages to the queue for the files that arrive in my s3 bucket. I then have a scheduled ECS task that kicks-off my application to process those files.

My application reads off the queue. Its scheduled to work thrice a day and it works fine. Yesterday, I noticed that there was an abnormal delay in the time from when the files arrived (when event trigger would run the lambda function) and when the messages were received on my queue. The delay was about 4 hours.

I have `Delivery Delay: 0 seconds`
and     Content-Based Deduplication:    Disabled
and its a FIFO queue if that makes any difference.

If anyone knows why this might be happening, that'd help!
Its hard to believe it to be an AWS glitch.

Comment: "there was an abnormal delay in the time from when the files arrived (when event trigger would run the lambda function) and when the messages were received on my queue. The delay was about 4 hours." - Lambda functions can only run for a maximum of 5 minutes (excluding any retries), so the data was either sent to your SQS queue, or it wasn't within that time.  Do you see any errors in the CloudWatch logs?

Comment: @JacobG. so there are no cloudwatch logs for that specific time when the object was created/added to the bucket. I guess that means the s3 event trigger is to blame for the delay and not the lambda function itself